# How can i sniff data from my iPhone safari under 2g/3g network

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

How can i sniff data from my iPhone safari under 2g/3g network. I can sniff data when my iPhone get wifi connection but i really want to check the data flow under 2g/3g network.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

If it's to test under network conditions I would suggest looking into the **Apple Network Link conditioner**. This utility will let you simulate real world network conditions such as `3G` or `Edge`.

Comment: Just like using fiddler or firebug network panel to watch http request.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the http requests your monitoring should be the same regardless. If your still adamant you can use a VPN to monitor it see this article [link](https://stevebranding.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/sniffing-3g-data/)